# Apple watch not syncing Health data

Tags: data-synchronization, apple-watch, core-storage, health.app

As the title suggests, my apple watch is working perfectly in termos of fitness tracking, the problem is in saving the data, the activity app on the Apple watch shows the activity rings full but the activity app on the iPhone has absolutely no data, also, the week summary, probably because there is no data stored, says I didn't move the whole week.

Already tried unpair and repair, didn't work.

[image: Activity rings]

[image: Activity app]

[image: Activity goals]

Thanks in advance,

Tiferrei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, jailbreak messed up the communication and file sharing with the Apple Watch, a DFU restore solved it.